# non-constant polynomials

Tags: polynomials

find a non-constant polynomial function $p(x)$ such that $p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=4$.
 I try to solve it but do not know where to start (every time I substitute a number into the equation, I get three more unknown numbers). Would anyone give me any clue? Is there a general method to deal with this kind of problems?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Any polynomial of shape $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)q(x)$ will be $0$ at $x=1,2,3$.

**Remark:** Alternately, we can start as you did, and try to find a cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ that will work. We get $3$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns, to which we can find a solution. Straightforward, but more calculation.

You asked for a general method. The idea of the hint above generalizes to **Lagrange Interpolation**.  If you want to use the machinery of Lagrange Interpolation, to make sure it does not give you the trivial answer $p(x)=4$, you can specify, for example, that $p(0)=0$.

Comment: i tried this was not correct

Comment: The hint is a tiny step away from a full answer. Of course $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is not $4$ at $1$, $2$, or $3$. But a very small modification will fix that. I can write it down if you wish.

Comment: @raheem That's why it's labeled as a hint, not a full answer.